# DetailView With Static Cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, master-detail, detailview

Im trying to create a Master detail View Application & I'm kinda stuck.

I have a tableView with 100 `DynamicPrototype` `Cells` showing Bars and when i tap on a `cell` i want to present more info about that Bar.

My question is how to fill different `data` like `labels` and `images` into the `DetailView` and change them for each `cell` i tap to represent the correct `data`

My `Detailview` is a `TableViewController` with `StaticCells` as shown here:

[image: Bars My Friends]

I am using Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8.1

I created a class to represent my DetailView Data :

## **BarProfile.Swift:**

```
import Foundation

class BarProfile {
    var HeaderImage = ""
    var HeaderTitle = ""
    var Age = ""
    var Adress = ""
    var Number = ""
    var Time = ""
    var Music = ""
    var Info = ""
    var Menu = ""
    var More = ""
    
    init(HeaderImage: String, HeaderTitle: String, Age: String, Adress: String, Number: String, Time: String, Music: String, Info: String, Menu: String, More: String) {
        
        
        self.HeaderImage = HeaderImage
        self.HeaderTitle = HeaderTitle
        self.Age = Age
        self.Adress = Adress
        self.Number = Number
        self.Time = Time
        self.Music = Music
        self.Info = Info
        self.Menu = Menu
        self.More = More
    
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: where is the answer for your question @NewBie Questions

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple you have just consider you are showing `headerTitle` in `viewController1` and if your select any row in `detailTableViewController` you are gonna to show `age`, `address` and `number`(You can show want ever you want by creating extra static cells and placing the label in it.)

**Your modified class:**

First declare all properties as optional and optional in init() method also

```
import Foundation

class BarProfile {
var HeaderImage: String?
var HeaderTitle: String?
var Age: String?
var Adress: String?
var Number: String?
var Time: String?
var Music: String?
var Info: String?
var Menu: String?
var More: String?

init(HeaderImage: String?, HeaderTitle: String?, Age: String?, Adress: String?, Number: String?, Time: String?, Music: String?, Info: String?, Menu: String?, More: String?) {


    self.HeaderImage = HeaderImage
    self.HeaderTitle = HeaderTitle
    self.Age = Age
    self.Adress = Adress
    self.Number = Number
    self.Time = Time
    self.Music = Music
    self.Info = Info
    self.Menu = Menu
    self.More = More

}
}
```

Populate the `ViewController1` table view as usual and when the user taps any cell pass that **selected object** to `detailTableViewController`. Create the segue from your table view cell in `ViewController1` to `detailTableViewController`.

**Code in ViewController1:**

```
class viewController1: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var barArray:[BarProfile] = []
var selctedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for _ in 0...5 { // Creating dummy object for clear understanding. 
        let barObject = BarProfile(HeaderImage: "werw", HeaderTitle: "erqwrw", Age: "34", Adress: "qwerwer", Number: "32", Time: "time", Music: "qerqw", Info: nil, Menu: nil, More: nil)
        barArray.append(barObject)
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return barArray.count
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell Identifier")! as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = barArray[indexPath.row].HeaderTitle
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selctedIndexPath = indexPath
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
// MARK: Navigation Methods

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifier" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? detailTableViewController
        detailViewController?.selectedBarObject = barArray[(selctedIndexPath?.row)!]
    }
}

}
```

**Code in your detailTableViewController:**

```
class detailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var selectedBarObject: BarProfile?

@IBOutlet var ageLabel: UILabel! // connect these outlets to your label in static cells.
@IBOutlet var addressLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numberLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if selectedBarObject != nil {
        showBarDetails()
    } else {
        // Do nothing 
    }
}

// You are going to use static cells so no need to implement table view data source methods

func showBarDetails() {
    ageLabel.text = selectedBarObject?.Age
    addressLabel.text = selectedBarObject?.Adress
    numberLabel.text = selectedBarObject?.Number
}

}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Hey , Thank you for your really impressive answer :) Right now its 6 Am so i will try to implement this  in the next day . Talk soon, And thank you again.

Comment: No mention, if it is worked accept and up vote my answer if you can.

Comment: Ok this messes up things for me . I already have a `tableView` with `data` and stuff I'm updating my answer right now to show you what i already have. i just need to change the `data` in the `detailView`

Comment: Have you updated your question? Whats your issue could you please make it clear?

Comment: I have a tableView populated with cells but if i press on one nothing happens at the moment . I want to implement a detailView application so i can press a cell and see more info about it , but i don't know how. I have connected a segue to a tableViewController to be my detailViewController and i want to change data depending on the indexPath so each cell has different data. By data i mean Labels and images in my case . You understand?

Comment: Same thing I have implemented in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Shalom, it's actually quite simple:

It seems your detail view is also a table view. So implement that the same way as the other table view.

Return your 8 cells, and create different cell prototypes (from the above screenshot, it seems you need three or so). In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you check which row you are in and populate the cell with the correct image and the correct data field from your `BarProfile` object (which should be an ivar of the view controller).

The image and title can be implemented as a `tableHeaderView`.

Comment: Cant i do it with StaticCells? Someone even told its even better than prototype cells

Comment: Seems less code to me though. You would have to define outlets and variables for all the icon fields, all the text fields in the cells, etc.